# The list is not transferred into the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I have a table `table1` in my database. This table have a column `column1` set to `varchar(20)`

I have all my data in `ArrayList<LatLng> list1`

Now i trying to insert my `list1` to `column1` but my idea didn't work:

```
 try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user1, pass1);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(list1)";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);



        }catch(SQLException se){

            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
            }
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: OP reposted better question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442503/try-to-convert-arraylistlatlng-to-string-before-insert-to-database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly insert a list in to Database . You are probably looking for

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(";
        for(String s : list1)
        {
          sql = sql+"'"+s+"'"; 
          }    
           sql=sql+")";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: looking good, but android studio underlines 'String s' and say : " required latlng, found string" its possible to convert this here ?

Comment: @patrick1980 so seems like you created your own variable named latIng, does it have certain values you want inserted in the object or what are you expecting to be inserted from each object

Comment: exacly adnroid studio say "required: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng    ,    found java.lang.String" ,  i don't have my own variable named latlng