# Try to convert Arraylist<LatLng> to string before insert to database

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist, foreach, tostring

I try to insert my `ArrayList<LatLng> list1` with a lot of values like this: `(99.9999999,99.9999999)` to table in database MySQL, exacly to 1 column, something like this:

```
row 1 (99.9999999,99.9999999)  
row 2 (99.9999999,99.9999999)  
row 3 (99.9999999,99.9999999)
```

...  all to 1 column.

In my opinion, currently i have a good method for this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(";
for(String s : list1) {
    sql = sql+"'"+s+"'"; 
}    
sql = sql+")";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

but Android Studio underlines `String s` and says:

```
Incompatible types
Required: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
Found: java.lang.String
```

In my opinion, Android Studio trying to say me: you need to convert all values from `ArrayList<LatLng> list1` to `String` !
Is it possible to convert all values from my `ArrayList` in one method ?

Comment: Which version of jave you are using?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no!!!!! Never store multiple values in a single column!!!

Comment: The first thing you should do is learn how to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-), so your Android app doesn’t contain a serious security hole known as SQL injection.

Comment: Aren't you missing a COMMA between each value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bad way of doing it:**

You can convert your data to string the following way:

```
for(LatLng s : list1)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('"+s+"');
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

That is, you don't have to do anything specific to convert it. I'm assuming you have the method toString() implemented in your LatLng class to give objects of LatLng type a meaningful string representation.

**Good way of doing it:**

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
for(LatLng s : list1){
    stmt.setString(1, s); // insert 's' in place of the 1st '?'
    stmt.addBatch();
}
stmt.executeBatch();
```

In this last case you are preparing a batch of commands to send at once to your database. This is much better than sending many sql statements because you end up having a lot less overhead. Also, you're not concatenating the sql statement by yourself. You give the initial sql statement with a '?' placeholder and then you insert the values with 'setString()' or 'setInt()' or whatever the type is of what you want to insert.

Comment: a little success ! but app adds all values to one row in table, do you know how to repair it ?

Comment: @patrick1980 My last edit should do what you need. Basically you're sending one insert command per line.

Comment: You've answered the question but are promoting bad programing so I've downvoted your answer.

Comment: @GeneMyers Yes, you are totally correct. I've edited my answer with a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Jose I've upvoted you again, but still patrick1980 should consider using a better datatype to store this value :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the ArrayList does not contain strings, not that you must convert to a string. You can not implicitly convert an array entry of type LatLng to a string as you have done.

Your `for` statement should be:

```
for(LatLng ll : list1)
```

You should store the LatLng value in a [point datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude) , assuming you are using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. As noted by @[juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) in your comments it's not a good practice to store a comma delimited string in a single column or quote the string yourself.

Here's a link explaining how to [store the LatLng data as a Point in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/how-to-insert-a-point-into-postgis). Alternatively, you could store the lat and lng separately in 'double precision' datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `toString` method on the `LatLng` instances to convert them to strings.
2. Do not attempt to quote parameters in SQL queries yourself; use the API's support for placeholders for that purpose. Trying to quote strings yourself makes it trivial for attackers to destroy or manipulate your database to their own ends.